# Why does `dae` command delete everything in a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

Recently I started exploring `vscodevim`, and knew about the `daw` command, that not just deletes before the next word, but completely deletes the current word too.
Logically, `dae` command would delete before the end of the word, but it, suddenly, just clears the file... So, what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `vscodevim`, the motion `ae` refers to the entire buffer, hence `dae` will delete it.

Note that this has nothing to do with the "real" Vim, that's not a valid command there. I would use `Gd1G` to have the same effect in Vim:

- `G` goes to the last line;
- `d1G` deletes from there to the first line.

Although there are no doubt other ways, Vim is nothing if not prolific in the varying ways to do things :-)